# Pass wildcard to process builder

Tags: java, c++, shell

In both Java and C++ arguments are wrapped by ' like :

```
system("cmd arg1 arg2");// C++
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd arg1 arg2");// Java
new ProcessBuilder("cmd","arg1","arg2").start();// Java
//=============== output
cmd 'arg1' 'arg2'
```

Which prevents arguments to be interpreted as wildcard like: l* will be interpreted as "lstar" not "l{everything-is-possible}"

Also if I add a ' ,it will converted to \'

How can I pass wildcard via these programming languages?

Comment: It is the shell that handles wildcards - if you aren't invoking a shell there is no one to handle the wildcards

Comment: Yeath thank you man I must run "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash  -c cmd arg1 arg2");.You can Answer it I will give it acceptation

Answer (score 0):

It is the shell (bash, csh) etc that handles wildcards and passes specific arguments to your process. For example you may run `ls *.txt` - the shell expands `*.txt` and calls `ls a.txt b.txt c.txt` (depending on what files exist in the current directory).

Calling `exec` doesn't invoke any shell and so there is no "wildcard handling".

Processes could do their own wildcard handling (`if (arg.equals("*")) { ...`) but I think it is pretty rare.

So either the calling process has to do the matching and pass the correct args to exec or you need to invoke exec with a shell like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c ls *.txt");`